# Why does page-anchor not work in Opera?

Tags: html, anchor, opera

I got the following webpage-builtup:

```
<div id="menu">
</div>

<div id="content">
    <!-- you just need to see the last part of the page? us this link -->
    <a href="#down">down</a>
    <!-- A LOT OF CONTENT ... no fun to scroll down -->

    <!-- EVEN MORE CONTENT ... still no fun to scroll down -->

    <a name="down" id="down" />
</div>
```

This works fine except Opera. Why is that? Does someone know a solution or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you provide URL or more content? That seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code. Except maybe for the fact that you're trying to self-close a tag that isn't a self-closer. In this case, the anchor tag. Close it properly at least.

But, tested in Opera 9.64 and it's working fine.

The expected outcome of that code chunk alone is to go right down to the named link, which it does.

If you have a clashing `ID` that you're not showing, that's probably a reason.

Comment: "There's nothing wrong with the code. Except maybe for the fact that you're trying to self-close a tag that isn't a self-closer. In this case, the anchor tag. Close it properly at least." ----> Well, I didn't know you had to close it ... Too much XML in my head, but that did the trick! Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working in Opera 10.0 on Windows Vista.

You must have some other problem, like a duplicate `name` or `id`, that Opera handles differently from other browsers.

Have you tried [validating your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Does not work in Opera 9.5.1 as thats what I'm using and how I found the same question. Might be a bug for that version of Opera